# Tower Defense: Overlapping Tower range

Tags: dynamic, game-physics

I'm planning on creating a tower defense game with a little dynamic approach. The scenario is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCkzt.png)

The red area will be the "killzone" where the tower placement/strategy of the player will utilized greatly.

What I want to happen is when a creep in a wave that has an "active shield buff" enters the killzone the creep will activate his skill to protect nearby creeps.

Is there an algorithm that would help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I think I will create colliders for those tower(both target and effect tower). Then, when the creep are insides those colliders' area at the same time. The effect should be activated.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check if the creep is inside each towers' radius. You do that by

```
function isInside(creep_pos, tower_pos, radius):
    return pow(creep_pos.x - tower_pos.x, 2) + pow(creep_pos.y - tower_pos.y, 2) < radius*radius
```

(purely Pythagoras' theorem)

Now, lets say you have two towers, `Tower t1, t2`. If the creep is inside both of the tower radiuses, you want to activate it:

```
Tower t1, t2
Creep c
if (isInside(c.pos, t1.pos, t1.r) && isInside(c.pos, t2.pos, t2.r))
    c.activeShield()
```

You can check against as many towers as you want by just `&&`-ing more of them together.